# webpack-dev-server 4 works, but webpack 5 fails to load icon

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server, salesforce-lightning

I am currently using Webpack version 5, Webpack-dev-server version 4, and Salesforce Lightning React Component. The webpack-dev-server can load the static icons successfully, but the webpack one cannot load.

Here is the image with webpack-dev-server version 4:
[Webpack-dev-server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rHhlY.png)

Here is the image with webpack version 5:
[Webpack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/itTUD.png)

Here is the snapshot of my code using Salesforce React Lightning:
[Salesforce React Lightning Component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F8TSJ.png)

Here is the folder structure of my project, and the location of my icon files: [Project Folder Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RdOwD.png)

In Salesforce React Component, they have the IconSettings with iconPath prop which you specify the location of the files, and an array which contain the "name" of the file, and the "category" of the file or the the name of the folder.

Here is my package.json script:

```
  "scripts": {
"start": "webpack serve",
"build": "webpack",
"test": "react-scripts test",
"eject": "react-scripts eject"}
```

Here is my webpack.config.js:

```
const path = require("path");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
    entry: "./src/index.tsx",
    output: { path: path.join(__dirname, "build"), filename: "index.bundle.js" },
    mode: process.env.NODE_ENV || "development",
    resolve: {
        extensions: [".tsx", ".ts", ".js"],
    },
    devServer: { static: [path.join(__dirname, "src"), path.join(__dirname, "public")], historyApiFallback: true },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: ["babel-loader"],
            },
            {
                test: /\.(ts|tsx)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: ["ts-loader"],
            },
            {
                test: /\.(css|scss)$/,
                use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"],
            },
            {
                test: /\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|mp3|mp4|ico|svg)$/,
                type: "asset/resource"
            }
        ],
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: path.join(__dirname, "public", "index.html"),
        }),
    ],
};
```

Here is my .babelrc file:

```
{
    "presets": [
        "@babel/env",
        "@babel/react",
        "@babel/preset-typescript",
        "@salesforce/babel-preset-design-system-react"
    ],
    "plugins": [
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread"
    ]
}
```

Comment: can you debug it or screenshot of dev tools what happen to that icon or i think it's not found

Comment: Hi @Jerson, I already edited my post and included the screenshot of my project folder and location of the file.

Comment: did you check if the asset is in build folder?

Comment: Hi @Jerson, the assets are not in the build folder how can you copy all of the assets file into the build folder?